# Typescript type for child component of a higher order component that adds a prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How do I add a typescript type for the `Button` component (below) so typescript knows the `increment` function has been injected by the `Counter` HOC?

I'm aware of the render props pattern and hooks. I'm looking specifically for a way to type child components that receive props by a parent component through `cloneElement`.

I have a feeling it has something to do with conditional types but not sure how to apply that. Is this even possible?

```js
import React from 'react';

const Button = ({ increment }) => (
  <button onClick={increment}>
    increment
  </button>
);

const Counter = ({ children }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const increment = () => setCount(count + 1)

  return (

  <div>
    count: {count}
    {React.cloneElement(children, { increment })}
  </div>
  );
}

const App = () => (
  <Counter>
    <Button>
      increment
    </Button>
  </Counter>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: try: { increment }: any
{ children }:any

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the way TypeScript handles types for JSX children is not great, and the same goes for `cloneElement`. In your case the `Button` would have to have an optional `increment` prop, meaning you'd later have to check for its existence.

I would recommend the following pattern:

```
import React, { ComponentType } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

interface InjectedCounterProps {
  increment: () => void;
}

interface ButtonOwnProps {
  foo: string;
}

type ButtonProps = ButtonOwnProps & InjectedCounterProps;

const Button = ({ increment }: ButtonProps) => (
  <button onClick={increment}>increment</button>
);

const createCounter = <P extends {}>(
  Component: ComponentType<P & InjectedCounterProps>
) => (props: P) => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const increment = () => setCount(count + 1);

  return (
    <div>
      count: {count}
      <Component {...props} increment={increment} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Counter = createCounter<ButtonOwnProps>(Button);

const App = () => <Counter foo="bar" />;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here we use a HOC to construct our component from a provided `Button` component, and we are able to constrain the types for this button to those injected by the HOC.

This also allows props applied to the returned component to be defined by the component we provide it. This is done through the generic `P` type parameter, and allows us to pass the `ButtonOwnProps`, enforcing that `foo` must then be provided when rendering our final `Counter`.

You'll notice we get a type error if you remove `foo="bar"` when rendering the `Counter`.